# Cannot install apps via macOS Big Sur App Store

Tags: install, mac-appstore, big-sur

Since upgrading to macOS Big Sur (11.1), my system has been slow and laggy. Many applications upon first action seems to require a 2-4 second load to become responsive - once they've recovered that first time, things seem to be about as fast as they were on Catalina (no measurements, just perceptual observation).

Recently, I tried to update Xcode to the latest (12.4) via the Mac App Store (3.0). The download seemed to complete, but the install wouldn't finish. I restarted the computer after 4 hours of not completing. Upon restarting, the install did not finish, so I thought I may need to reclaim some disk space. I went to download "Cleaner One - Disk Clean" from the Mac App Store. The app seemed to download but, too, could not finish the install. I restarted the computer again and tried to install the app again.

[image]

This time, it doesn't seem to even start the download, it just hangs at what appears to be 0% - the Launchpad says "Waiting". After this I decided to try, another app that I've never downloaded before (Just a random featured free app) "MindNode - Mind Map & Outline". This time the download starts and seemingly finishes, but stops at the end of the download and fails to install (the same thing I saw with the first attempt of installing "Cleaner One").

[image]

Something is obviously pretty borked here. I'm hoping someone knows somewhere to look to clean out whatever caches are preventing these from completing. I would go back to Catalina, but I think I need the latest macOS for the latest Xcode to develop for the latest iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. I found an Apple Developer forum (that I had to access [via Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LTGGo_zkJ2wJ:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662756+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari) for some reason) that discussed related issues.

To re-iterate here:

1. Sign out of Mac App Store

   - Store > Sign Out
   - [image]
2. Navigate to `~/Library/Caches` in Finder

   - Keyboard Shortcut `Cmd+Shift+G` *(Go to Folder)*
   - Enter `~/Library/Caches`
   - [image]
   - Click "Go"
3. Find the following folders in the Finder window and move them to the trash

   - `com.apple.appstore`
   - `com.apple.appstoreagent`
4. Reboot

   -  > Restart...
5. Launch Mac App Store & Sign in

Testing App Store downloads/installs after the above steps seems to have resolved the issues.

Answer (score -3):

Sometime also if you go to system preferences then Security then unlock the lock thing in the left corner then choose to allow third party apps . Then get the app you want then lock it up back to just allow Apple apps again.